# Insert text between two lines

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I am trying to insert one line between the below lines

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
<insert the text here>
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Add some context, please. Do you need to do this often, or on many servers? What would be wrong with a one-off use of a text editor?

Comment: i am trying to add the line using shell scripting, it was part of hardening the servers

Comment: tried some commands but not working

Comment: Without some guaranteed specifier (either a line number or some uniqueness of the text), the word "here" has no meaning. Nor is "some commands" any kind of a clarification.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to insert a new line as the 2nd line in the file, as the last-but-one line in the file, after the first/last/all line(s) matching the string `sufficient` (or any other substring on that line), or before the first/last/all line(s) matching `requisite` (or any other substring on that line). It's further unclear whether there are more lines in the file and what they look like. For all we know, you would be better served by just writing three static lines to the file, overwriting whatever may be in the file already, for simplicitly.

Comment: What is MWE input and expected output? And what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague, but this might do.

```
$ cat 2-lines 
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
```

Apply the append command of GNU `sed` after line 1:

```
$ sed '1a new line inserted' 2-lines 
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
new line inserted
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
```

To insert a line after the one that contains PATTERN, change 1a above to /PATTERN/a